# PyGI: Styling Context Menu

Tags: css, python-3.x, gtk3, pygi-aio

I'm using PyGI to build a GUI for an app I've written in Python 3.4, and I'm using GTK+3's CSS implementation to style the interface.

In my .css file, I've specified that all text by default should be white:

```
* {
    color: #fff;
}
```

as I'm mostly working against dark/black backgrounds.

The app I'm building has text boxes, however, and GTK automatically gives them [context/right-click menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/975M7.png). Unfortunately the default white text styling I've applied also works on the menu, and so the user can't see anything.

If I try to override those settings with:

```
.menu {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

it just turns out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm9pF.png). The text colour doesn't change, and it doesn't seem to respond to any `:disabled` pseudo-classes either.

How can I style or customise the context menus of these text fields using GTK+3's implementation of CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I styled the context menu to look the way I want with these lines in the CSS file:

```
.menu {
    border: 1px #444 solid;

    background: #0d0d0d;

    font: light 12px;
}
.menu .separator {
    color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.1);
}
.menuitem {
    padding: 8px 0px;
}
.menuitem:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
.menuitem:insensitive .label {
    color: #555;
}
```

[It now looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeJ8o.png)